# A tricky integral

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, integration

Let $\alpha>0$ and $\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. I am looking for an explicit formula for the integral

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} (1+x^2)^{-1/2}e^{-\alpha x^2}e^{-i \beta x}dx.$$

I tried several changes of variables, and contour integration doesn't seem to work.

Motivation comes from the following closely related kernel
$$K(s,t)=e^{-\frac{(s-t)^2}{4}}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}(1+x^2)^{-1/2}e^{-\frac{(s-t)^2}{4} x^2}e^{-i (s^2-t^2) x}dx,$$ 
which provides an example of a compact integral operator on $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ that is not Hilbert-Schmidt. I would like to check the details.

Thank you!

Comment: This looks like a Fourier-integral of a product of two functions. The convolution theorem could be helpful, but I don't have the time to work out the details right now...

Comment: Are you sure there is an explicit formula? By Dirk's comment, using the convolution theorem, your integral is fairly close to the convolution of a Whittaker function with a gaussian (there is some work needed, as the Fourier transform of the first function is not absolutely convergent, but it can be rewritten to be so). 

Comment: Maybe this is not helpful, but $K$ solves the heat equation: $\frac{\partial^2 K}{\partial t^2} = \frac{\partial K}{\partial s}$. But unfortunately $s,t$ are the wrong way round: $s$ is the time variable, $t$ the space variable!! I would suggest swapping $s,t$ around to make the notation easier, unless you have some strong reason to keep $s,t$ as you've written.

Comment: You are told that $K$ provides an example of a compact integral operator? Is $K$ supposed to be the integral kernel (that would be suspicious since you restrict $s > 0$)? What is the operator you actually have and what is the Hilbert space you are working over? 

Comment: "I am told", eh?  Well, if they told it to you in this form, then presumably they do not know an explicit formula for it either.


Comment: For expression in terms of special functions, my gut feeling is "Bessel function". Unfortunately ten pleasant minutes with Watson doesn't prove to me it is more-or-less a Bessel function; but then it doesn't prove to me it isn't since there are related classical integrals. The point about Bessel functions is often that they have known asymptotic behaviour, and not just in the independent variable. So, given the type of question you are asking, this could be Bessel or Bessel-like, and the point may not be the formula, but matching asymptotics to a function you can write down. A theory, anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Neither Maple nor Wolfram Alpha (http://www.wolframalpha.com) gives a closed form for this integral (even after inserting numeric values for $\alpha$ and $\beta$).  That probably means that there isn't one.  If $\beta=0$ then Wolfram Alpha gives an answer of $e^{\alpha/2}K_0(\alpha/2)$, where $K_0$ is a Bessel function.

Answer (score 0):

You can express it as a (formal) sum over terms which involve the Hermite polynomials, in the form $HermiteH(n,\frac{\beta}{2\sqrt{\alpha}})$.  You can compute the exact term from
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} x^n e^{-\alpha x^2}e^{-i\beta x}dx.$$

Since this involves summing over the index of a polynomial, the techniques I know stop working.

Note that for $\alpha=0$ this is $-\frac{\pi}{2}\left( Y_0(\beta i) + Y_0(-\beta i)\right)$ (again, Bessel function).  So with Neil's answer for $\beta=0$ and the 'hint' that this integral satisfies the Heat equation (see Zen's comment), you get another equivalent formulation of the problem.